Microsoft Workflow Manager V1 EOL
Our security team has suggested there is Microsoft Workflow Manager V1.0 installed around 5000 machines/servers. In our environment, we do not have SharePoint On-premises at all as everything is O365. We think that it was all some legacy installs which were done way back and we dont know how they were installed. Question now is,

What will be the implications of uninstalling them?
Will SPO workflow be impacted by this?
I understand, SP 2013 workflows can still work if you have or install SharePoint designer 2013.

Any help here is much appreciated.

Uninstalling Microsoft Workflow Manager V1.0 from your machines/servers should not impact SharePoint Online workflows as they are not dependent on Workflow Manager. However, if you have any SharePoint 2013 workflows, they will stop working as they require Workflow Manager. It is recommended to migrate these workflows to Power Automate or other supported solutions.
